# Google My Business API use of filter parameter is not clear

Tags: google-my-business-api

I use the GMB API to retrieve location information from my GMB account. No problem if I want to select all locations, but I am not able to select a relevant subset using the filter-parameter.

When retrieving all locations I use:

GET https://mybusiness.googlapis.com/v4/accounts/xxxx/locations

When I use filtering I do this:

```
GET https://mybusiness.googlapis.com/v4/accounts/xxxx/locations?filter=%22storeCode='RT-1'%22
--> this still gives all results

GET https://mybusiness.googlapis.com/v4/accounts/xxxx/locations?filter=%22location.storeCode='RT-1'%22
--> this still gives all results 

GET https://mybusiness.googlapis.com/v4/accounts/xxxx/locations?filter=%22store_code='RT-1'%22
--> this still gives all results

GET https://mybusiness.googlapis.com/v4/accounts/xxxx/locations?filter=%22location.store_code='RT-1'%22
--> this still gives all results

GET https://mybusiness.googlapis.com/v4/accounts/xxxx/locations?filter=store_code=%22'RT-1'%22
--> gives no results, but also not an error message

GET https://mybusiness.googlapis.com/v4/accounts/xxxx/locations?filter=store_code=%22RT-1%22
--> gives no results, but also not an error message

GET https://mybusiness.googlapis.com/v4/accounts/xxxx/locations?filter=location.store_code=%22RT-1%22
--> gives no results, but also not an error message

GET https://mybusiness.googlapis.com/v4/accounts/xxxx/locations?filter=location.storeCode=%22RT-1%22
--> gives no results, but also not an error message

Could someone please point me a working solution?

I read through pages of documentation, but they give different stories. I also tried to filter with other attributes, but that appears not to be different. Next to that, the Google documentation states I can use all fields to filter.

To support my statements I used OAuth2 playground, so no programming issues. Authentication is not the problem since I can retrieve the complete list of locations.

Hope someone can help me! And if you also have an example of the 'orderBy' parameter that would be great!

Leon
```

Answer (score 0):

We've been struggeling with the same problem and Google's documentation is pretty helpless as their own examples in regard to the storeCode just do not work.

What in fact seems to be working is filtering by location_name/locationName and flicking in your Store-Code there (don't ask me why, of course that doesn't make any sense).

So you would have to call the API like that:

```
GET
https://mybusiness.googlapis.com/v4/accounts/xxxx/locations?filter=location_name="RT-1"

GET
https://mybusiness.googlapis.com/v4/accounts/xxxx/locations?filter=locationName="RT-1"
```

Doesn't seem to make any difference if you use upperCamelCase or not.

Best regards, Marc